# mosquitto 1.4 - once running with ACL enabled, gets "Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting"

Tags: acl, mosquitto

following instructions from Jeremy Gooch, see http://goochgooch.co.uk/2014/08/01/building-mosquitto-1-4/, i installed mosquitto over websockets on RPi. i can sub/pub messages to test site http://test.mosquitto.org/ws.html

from that point, i enabled user and topic access control in mosquitto.conf for more tests, but the strange point is that when i start mosquitto again, i see socket errors per second...

```
sudo /usr/local/sbin/mosquitto -v -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf

 1429857948: mosquitto version 1.4 (build date 2015-04-20 22:04:51+0800) starting
1429857948: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1429857948: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1429857948: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1429857948: Warning: Address family not supported by protocol
1429857949: New connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 1883.
1429857949: Sending CONNACK to 127.0.0.1 (0, 5)
1429857949: Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.
1429857950: New connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 1883.
1429857950: Sending CONNACK to 127.0.0.1 (0, 5)
...
```

i modify the config file to enable ACL only, comment out all others, the socket errors are still there. config file looks now:

```
sudo nano /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf

autosave_interval 1800
persistence true
persistence_file m2.db
persistence_location /var/tmp/
connection_messages true
log_timestamp true
log_dest stderr
log_type error
log_type warning
log_type debug

allow_anonymous false
password_file /etc/mosquitto/mqtt.pw
acl_file /etc/mosquitto/mqtt.acl

port 1883
protocol mqtt
```

i even test to use the sample password_file and acl_file, but same error. 
searched on google, also no result, could anyone help on this? thanks.

Comment: debug further:  
when i comment out “allow_anonymous false” in the config file, the result turns to be:  
    
    1429879181: New connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 1883.
    1429879181: New client connected from 127.0.0.1 as paho/75CA8C7DEF44E69793 (c1, k60).
    1429879181: Sending CONNACK to paho/75CA8C7DEF44E69793 (0, 0)
    1429879241: Received PINGREQ from paho/75CA8C7DEF44E69793
    1429879241: Sending PINGRESP to paho/75CA8C7DEF44E69793
    
any hints of that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 1429857949: Sending CONNACK to 127.0.0.1 (0, 5)

CONNACK return code of 5 means the connection was not authorised. If it
works with allow_anonymous=true, then it sounds like your client isn't
sending a username / or isn't sending a correct username&password.

It looks like you have a Paho Python client running.

Comment: thanks, ralight.  i am sure i ran the broker only, i didn't run other python client.
at the moment when i saw this "error", it popped up per 1 or 2 sec, yesterday i noticed it turned to be every 3 or 5 mins, then in the evening it suddenly disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem my solution was that I wasn't closing the connection. Once I added client.Disconnect() it solved my problem.

Code:

```
public IEnumerator ooverhere()
{
    MqttClient client;
    client = new MqttClient(urlPath, port, false, MqttSslProtocols.None, null, null);
    client.ProtocolVersion = MqttProtocolVersion.Version_3_1;

    byte code = client.Connect(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), user, pass);
    if (code == 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("successful connection ...");

        //client.MqttMsgPublishReceived += client_recievedMessage;

        Debug.Log("your client id is: " + client.ClientId);

        client.Subscribe(new string[] { "example" }, new byte[] { 0 });
        client.Publish("Helpme", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("@" + 0));
        yield return client;

        client.Disconnect();
    }
}
```